# OpenGL ES iPhone, corrupt image when using glClearColor

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm just starting to learn about OpenGL ES on the iPhone. I trying to get a very simple example working that sets up an EAGLContext and render buffer then simply uses glClearColor to set the screen color.

My code compiles and executes but unfortunately, instead of the expected grey screen, I see a a white image with a random corruption pattern. I'm guessing I havent set things up correctly and I'm hoping that my mistake will be obvious to someone with a little experience in this area.

My code is:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import "GLView.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
@private
  UIWindow* m_window;
  GLView* m_view;
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GLView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication*) application
{
  CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

  m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
  m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];

  [m_window addSubview: m_view];
  [m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
  [m_view release];
  [m_window release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

GLView.h

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface GLView : UIView {
@private
  EAGLContext* m_context;

}

- (void) drawView;

@end
```

GLView.mm

```
#include <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#include <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
#import "GLView.h"

@implementation GLView

+ (Class) layerClass
{
  return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

      //Set up the layer and context
      CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) super.layer;
      eaglLayer.opaque = YES;

      m_context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

      if (!m_context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
      }

      // Create & bind the color buffer so that the caller can allocate its space.
      GLuint renderbuffer;
      glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &renderbuffer);
      glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
      [m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:eaglLayer];
      glViewport(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetHeight(frame));

      [self drawView];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawView
{
  glClearColor(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  [m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
  if([EAGLContext currentContext] == m_context)
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
  [m_context release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find documentation that spells it out explicitly either way but I think you may simply need to create a frame buffer explicitly. In GL a render buffer is anything that some component of the outgoing fragments can be written to — so a colour buffer like the one you've created or a depth buffer or a stencil buffer or anything else like that. A frame buffer is a collection of render buffers that constitutes a drawing target.

So it's all fairly trivial stuff but what you'd add is a call to `glGenFramebuffersOES` and then to `glBindFramebufferOES` prior to `glBindRenderbufferOES` (as that binds the render buffer in the context of the frame buffer). And in case you ever add render-to-texture or decide to use Apple's multisampling extension it's the frame buffer you'll bind and unbind, not the render buffer.

As a verification of correctness, you should also make a call to `glCheckFramebufferStatusOES` after you've bound and created the render buffers you want — just something quick like:

```
if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
{
    // some sort of error path here
}
```

That'll help eliminate one area of investigation if you're still getting nonsensical pixel output.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include a line after

```
[m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:eaglLayer];
////
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, renderbuffer);
////
```

and also the condition

```
if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES)
```

is always true !!! Eventhough I am getting desired out put.